# How to modify this to not be two components in React

Tags: reactjs

NOTE: I HAVE REPLACED THIS QUESTION WITH ONE WITH MORE CLARITY AT THE LOCATION: [Context not returned when referencing React component as function instead of JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73674507/context-not-returned-when-referencing-react-component-as-function-instead-of-jsx)

I WOULD LIKE TO DELETE THIS BUT SO WILL NOT LET ME.

I have the following JavaScript file that is one React component calling another one nested inside it. I want to change this to not use the name of the nested component but instead create the internal component as an anonymous one.

I want to usr the JavaScript name and not return JSX.

Here is my original working component

```
const InsideComponent = () => {
 
  return (
    <div>
      Inside Component
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Speakers() {
  return (
    <div>
      <InsideComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've tried a few combinations including this below that do not work

```
export default function Speakers() {
  return (
    <div>
      { 
         return (
           { InsideComponent()}
         )
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `{` inside the context of JSX stops the JSX syntax and begins a plain JavaScript expression. (Not a function - no `return`.) So from here

```
    <div>
      {
```

for the syntax to be valid, you'd need to have an expression that evaluates to a JSX element:

```
export default function Speakers() {
  return (
    <div>
      { 
         (
           <div>
             Inside Component
           </div>
         )
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

But the nesting of a JavaScript expression isn't useful at all there - better to just insert the plain JSX instead.

```
export default function Speakers() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        Inside Component
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: My real code is more complex.  I made the example a trivial simple example

Comment: What is the *actual* code you have?

Comment: It involves using context as the wrapper and I’m trying to avoid creating a named function (InsideComponent)

Comment: Can't debug code we can't see...

Answer (score 0):

When you want to merge components, you just need to merge the JSX portion of it.

In your example, you can just do

```
export default function Speakers() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
         Inside Component
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I meant I want to return JavaScript and not jsx

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
export default function Speakers() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        Inside Component
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Unless you're using the `InsideComponent` as part of other components, there is no need to separate the two. But if you want to, just use it like you would any other component.

```
export default function Speakers() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <InsideComponent />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function Speakers() {
  return (
    <div>
           <div>
             Inside Component
           </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is this is what you are looking for?